# MYSQL Error - with PHP For LOOP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm aware that questions shouldn't be asked when it concerns a syntax error, however, I'm at a total loss as to why the following error is being thrown:

**PHP & MYSQL CODE**

```
//Possible size array to loop through when checking quantity
    $con_size = array (26,28,30,32,33,34,35,355,36,365,37,375,38,385,39,395,
                       40,405,41,415,42,425,43,435,44,445,45,455,46,465,47,475,48,485);
    $arrayLength=count($con_size);

        for($x=0;$x<$arrayLength;$x++)
        {

    // check if size is available
    if($line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x].'_con_b'] > 0 )
    {

        $quantity = $line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x].'_con_b'];
        $current = $line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x]];
        $id = $line ['product_id'];


        $data = "UPDATE product_test
        SET quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x] = $quantity + $current,
        quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x]_con_b = 0
        WHERE product_id = $id";

        $result2 = mysql_query($data);

        if ($result2)
        {
            echo 'Stock Updated <br />';
        }
        else
        {
            echo mysql_error();
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

**MYSQL ERROR**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' quantity_c_size_40_con_b = 0 WHERE product_id = 12897' at line 2
```

I've tried the MYSQL query within PHPMyAdmin using the same `UPDATE` syntax above and the query completes successfully. However, when it runs within the PHP FOR loop it throws the above error.

I'm probably missing something completely obvious, but for now I'm stumped.

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Echo out the query and show us what it's generating.

Comment: One does not simply use "quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x]"... you must use "quantity_c_size_" . $con_size[$x] . "...";

Comment: I strongly suspect it does not like the array notation. Extract the variables from the arrays first, assign them to variables, and use those variables in your `$data` string.

Comment: Or using curly braces: "quantity_c_size_{$con_size[$x]}..."

Comment: Or better, wrap in `{}` as `quantity_c_size_{$con_size[$x]}`

Comment: Try running the loop but restrict it to one element less ($x<$arrayLength-1).  It may be trying to grab one item too many outside the array bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Andrew's suggestion, I echoed out the UPDATE query and found the `$current` variable was NULL and so the addition calculation within the statement could not complete.

I amended the code as follows:

```
//Possible size array to loop through when checking quantity
    $con_size = array (26,28,30,32,33,34,35,355,36,365,37,375,38,385,39,395,
                       40,405,41,415,42,425,43,435,44,445,45,455,46,465,47,475,48,485);
    $arrayLength=count($con_size);

        for($x=0;$x<$arrayLength;$x++)
        {

    // check if size is available
    if($line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x].'_con_b'] > 0 )
    {

        $quantity = $line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x].'_con_b'];

        if ($line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x]] == NULL)
        {
            $current = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            $current = $line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x]];

        }

        $id = $line ['product_id'];


        $data = "UPDATE product_test
        SET quantity_c_size_{$con_size[$x]} = $quantity + $current,
        quantity_c_size_{$con_size[$x]}_con_b = 0
        WHERE product_id = $id";

        ...
```